# Symfony 6 json_login "missing credentials"

Tags: php, typescript, symfony, yaml, symfony6

I am trying to get a json_api based login system working in my project.
My problem is that when i click my login button, I get an unauthorized error message that there are missing credentials. When i dump the user in the response it shows that it is null.

Here is my controller function:

```php
    #[Route('/entry/login', name: 'api_login')]
    public function login(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user): Response
    {
        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->json([
                'message' => 'missing credentials',
                'user' => $user
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return $this->json(['user' => $user->getUserIdentifier()]);
    }
```

My security.yaml:

```yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
  
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                class: 'App\Entity\User'
                property: 'email'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            json_login:
                check_path: api_login
```

and my front-end post request:

```js
private async submit(): Promise<void> {
        if ((this as any).$refs.form.validate() && this.valid) {
            const user = {
                username: this.email,
                password: this.password,
            }

            const response = await axios.post('/entry/login', user);
        }
    }
```

I have been referencing [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#json-login) page, and I think my code should work like this but it seems that i am missing something.

Any help would be appreciated.

If you need more code or anything you may ask.

Comment: Please try to set `username_path: email` under json_login (because you are using entity property email). And change username -> email in your frontend request.

Comment: Second guess would be to check `access_control` section under firewall.

Comment: thanks! the username_path fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Please try to set following fields explicitly (username_path & password_path):

```
firewall:
    main:
        lazy: true
        json_login:
            check_path: api_login
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
```

Because you are using entity `property: 'email'`. Also change `username` to `email` in your frontend request.